# CustomSearchBar color differs from the one in UINavigationBar

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

Im using:

```
#define colorApp  [UIColor colorWithRed:254/256.f green:64/256.f blue:89/256.f alpha:1.0]
```

Inside the customSearchView init:

```
    [self setBackgroundColor:colorApp];
    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    searchBar.barTintColor = colorApp;
    [self addSubview:searchBar];
```

Getting the next result:

[image]

I need the searchBarTint color to be the same as the navigation. Translucent doesn't seem to make the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the fix soon after I posted the question.

In case anyone ever faces this problem I used

```
 [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pinkBar.png"]
                                                forBarPosition:0
                                                    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

It seems backgroundColor and barTintColor aren't taking colors same way as the navigation for a UISearchDisplayController since iOS 7. But adding an image with that color just resolves that.

I know it's just a quick fix but it helped me and could help others as it is a minor visual issue.